# Adapt drawing shape in 3.5inch and 4inch screen

Tags: ios, iphone, coordinates, shapes, drawrect

I am a new ios developer and here's my problem.I draw a shape with this code :

```
-(void)drawFirstShape:(float)xcoord :(float)ycoord :(CGContextRef)c {

float cote = 70.0f;
float x = 60.0f;
float y = 35.0f;
CGFloat strokecolor[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, strokecolor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 4.0f);
CGContextBeginPath(c);
CGContextMoveToPoint(c, xcoord, ycoord);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, xcoord+x, ycoord+y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, xcoord+x, ycoord+cote+y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, xcoord, ycoord+cote+2*y);
CGContextClosePath(c);
CGContextDrawPath(c, kCGPathStroke);
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self drawFirstShape:160.0f :100.0f:c];
}
```

I want to create relative coordinates instead of absolute ones.
The aim is to stabilize this code to use it with a 3.5inch and 4inch screen. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use relative coordinates then use relative coordinates :)
All positions and width/height should be defined as float or double from 0 to 1.

Then to get real coordinate - just multiply these relative coordinates to frame sizes (or to rect in your case) and you will get absolute coordinates or sizes.

Example (I just used your code with small changes. keep in mind that I changed sizes to relative and you will need to change them to be correct ones):

```
-(void)drawFirstShape:(float)xcoord :(float)ycoord :(CGContextRef)c inRect:(CGRect)rect{
    xcoord = xcoord*rect.size.width;
    ycoord = ycoord*rect.size.height;

    float cote = 0.07f*rect.size.width;
    float x = 0.05f*rect.size.width;
    float y = 0.025f*rect.size.height;
    CGFloat strokecolor[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, strokecolor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 4.0f);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, xcoord, ycoord);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, xcoord+x, ycoord+y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, xcoord+x, ycoord+cote+y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, xcoord, ycoord+cote+2*y);
    CGContextClosePath(c);
    CGContextDrawPath(c, kCGPathStroke);
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self drawFirstShape:0.2 :0.1 :c inRect:rect];
}
```

Comment: I tried with this     
CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c,0.5, 0.5);
CGContextClosePath(c);
CGContextDrawPath(c, kCGPathStroke);
But it doesn't work. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Thanks for the edited code. I changed in the simulator to 3.5inch device and I put those NSLog :    NSLog(@" width %f",rect.size.width);
    NSLog(@" height %f",rect.size.height);
For the 3.5inch and 4inch the result is the same width 640 and height 960. Thus my shape remains the same. Do you know why it's happening?

Comment: Did you use auto layout in storyboard? Without auto layout your view will have the same size as you define it in storyboard, no matter which device you are running on.
Use auto layout and make your view to take full screen and then it will be different

Comment: I just checked. In the interface builder in the File inspector the Auto Layout is checked.